# Accurately Timing RSpec Specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, time, rspec

I have 2 tests. One with a database call and one that uses a double. I'd like to understand the performance difference between them. I realize this is likely to be pretty small, but I'm just trying to get a better sense of the latency aspect of the trade off when opting to use a stub or an actual call to the db.

I originally thought this would be as simple as running something like

```
time rspec spec_with_db_spec.rb
```

and

```
time rspec spec_with_double_spec.rb
```

independently and maybe a bunch of times over and over in random order so I could take the averages, however, I'm running into some issues.

1. It seems like `time` might not be the best way, as it could happen to coincide with a particularly expensive process occurring on my computer at the same time. I suppose running it over and over could help with that, but I'm not sure.
2. I realized I could maybe use RSpec's time output, but based on (albeit old) posts, it seems like that may not be reliable.

Does anyone have ideas for this? It doesn't need to be perfect, but just something I could run and see a difference and how much that difference approximately is (order of magnitude is fine).

Comment: Perhaps you could use Rubys [Benchmark module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) inside a spec. But the acuity of your test should really be a bigger concern if the difference is negible. Mocking has a tendency to plaster over bugs and inconsistencies that your tests are supposed to prevent.

Comment: Totally agree that this should not be the primary driving factor when opting to pick a db call or a double, but I am still curious nonetheless.

Comment: This is for my personal learning, not work by the way.

Comment: I have just used the `--profile` option when running RSpec in the past when I run into a slow test suite. It shows you what the slowest specs are. It  won't really do the same thing as a benchmark but it does help you find the problem areas.

Comment: Totally. That would be a great approach for an existing codebase.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Rubys built in [Benchmark tool](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html):

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'benchmark' # from the stdlib

RSpec.describe 'Benchmark' do
  let(:create_bm) do
    Benchmark.bm { FactoryBot.create_list(:user, 100) } 
  end

  let(:build_bm) do
    Benchmark.bm { FactoryBot.build_list(:user, 100) } 
  end

  it 'can give you the total time' do
    pending "Creating the list took #{create_bm.total} seconds"
  end

  specify 'you do not need two separate spec files' do
    pending "Building the list took #{build_bm.total} seconds"
  end

  specify 'stubbing is faster' do
    expect(build_bm.total).to be < create_bm.total
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `time` on an rspec test will not produce accurate results. The time will include all the other things a test has to do: loading Ruby, loading gems, and the rspec framework. This can swamp the time the code you're trying to benchmark takes.

You'll have only run the test once, it must be run many times to get an accurate result. And by running the different tests in different processes at different times might mean they're subject to different circumstances on a machine. For example, what if one runs just as your anti-virus starts running?

Instead, use the [built in Benchmark module](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html). These will only count the time taken by the benchmarked code.

Comment: Do you have documentation that elaborates more on, "randomly interleave the benchmarks so any events on your computer that might affect the benchmark affects them all"? I didn't see it in the benchmark documentation

Comment: @stk1234 You're right, it doesn't. And all the looping is up to you. I assumed it did those things because that's how a good benchmark module should behave.

Comment: Ok, no worries! Just wanted to make sure I didn't miss another source you read it from.